# iTextSharp aspx to pdf, Server.Execute error

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, pdf, itext

In ASP.net I have made webpage which is used to fill in an offer form.
There are 3 divs. The left div which has the TextBoxes to fill in.
The middlesector which is the form itself.
The right div which has the buttons.

So far I've been able to export only the midlesector to PDF with the stuff I filled in on the left and all. The problem is that it completely neglects the CSS, which has been made using absolute positioning. Therefore I would like to ask how to include the CSS style so that it looks the way it's supposed to instead of one continuous text.

This is the code for the middlesector:

```
<div id="middlesector" runat="server">
<%--><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>--%>
<asp:Image ID="TextArea1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images\VisserGroup.png"></asp:Image>
<label id="textarea2" runat="server" cols="20" name="S2"></label>
<label id="textarea3" runat="server" cols="20" name="S3">Visser International Trade & Engineering</label>
<label id="textarea4" runat="server" cols="20" name="S4">T.a.v</label>
<label id="textarea5" runat="server" cols="20" name="S5">Postbus</label>
<label id="textarea6" runat="server" name="S6"></label>
<label id="textarea7" runat="server" cols="20" name="S7"></label>
<label id="textarea8" runat="server" cols="20" name="S8"></label>
<label id="textarea9" runat="server" name="S9"></label>
<label id="textarea10" runat="server" cols="20" name="S10"></label>
<label id="textarea11" runat="server" cols="20" name="S11"></label>
<label id="textarea12" runat="server" cols="20" name="S12">-OFFERTE-</label>
<label id="textarea13" runat="server" name="S13">Geachte</label>
<label id="textarea14" runat="server" name="S14"></label>
<label id="textarea15" runat="server" cols="20" name="S15">Met referte aan het aangename onderhoud hebben wij het genoegen u bijgaand onze offerte te doen toekomen voor het leveren van:</label>
<label id="textarea16" runat="server" cols="20" name="S16"></label>
<label id="TextArea17" runat="server" cols="20" name="S17">Wij danken u voor deze aanvraag en hopen u hiermee een passend voorstel te hebben gedaan. Voor het bespreken van verdere details en toelichting op de offerte zullen wij op korte termijn contact met u opnemen. Indien u direct uw eventuele vragen aan ons wenst voor te leggen dan horen wij dit graag van u.</label>
<label id="TextArea18" runat="server" cols="20" name="S18">Wij vertrouwen u hiermee voldoende van dienst te zijn en houden ons van harte aanbevolen voor uw gewaardeerde opdracht.</label>
<label id="TextArea19" runat="server" cols="20" name="S19">Met vriendelijke groet,Visser Supplies B.V.</label>
<label id="TextArea20" runat="server" cols="20" name="S20">Personal info</label>
<label id="TextArea21" runat="server" cols="20" name="S21">Website          : www.vissersupplies.nl</label>
<label id="TextArea22" runat="server" cols="20" name="S22">E-mail           : personal info</label>
<label id="TextArea23" runat="server" cols="20" name="S23">Telefoonnummer   : personal info 9894</label>
<label id="TextArea24" runat="server" cols="20" name="S24">Copyright Visser Supplies B.V.:</label>
<label id="TextArea25" runat="server" cols="20" name="S25">Deze offerte en alle andere informatie mogen alleen door geadresseerde gebruikt worden. Overdracht aan derden, in welke vorm dan ook,  is slechts toegestaan na schriftelijk toestemming van Visser Supplies B.V.</label>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#middlesector {
        position:absolute; left: 150px; top: 60px;
    }
#TextArea1 {
        height: 250px;
        width:  640px;
        position: absolute; top:-40px;
        border:none;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
    }

   #textarea2 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 105px;
       width: 320px;
       position:absolute; top:220px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea3 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 30px;
       width: 310px;
       position:absolute; top:215px;
       left: 410px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea4 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 310px;
       position:absolute; top:250px;
       left: 410px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea5 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 310px;
       position:absolute; top:270px;
       left: 410px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea6 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 100px;
       position:absolute; top:290px;
       left: 410px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea7 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 310px;
       position:absolute; top:310px;
       left: 410px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea8 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 210px;
       position:absolute; top:290px;
       left: 480px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea9 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 130px;
       position:absolute; top: 360px; 
       left: 360px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }
   #textarea10 {
       height: 15px;
       width: 180px;
       position:absolute; top:360px;
       left: 450px;
       border:none;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
   }

   #textarea11 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 320px;
       position:absolute; top:360px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #textarea12 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       font-size: large;
       font-weight: bold;
       height: 25px;
       width: 120px;
       position:absolute; top:400px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       left: 270px;
   }

   #textarea13 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 75px;
       position:absolute; top:450px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #textarea14 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       height: 15px;
       width: 200px;
       position:absolute; top:450px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       left: 65px;
       margin-left: auto;
   }

   #textarea15 {
        height: 30px;
        width:  640px;
        text-align:start;
        text-anchor:end;
        position: absolute; top:480px;
        border:hidden;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
        left: 0px;
    }

   #textarea16 {
       border-style: none;
       border-color: inherit;
       border-width: medium;
       font-size:large;
       font-weight: bold;
       height: 25px;
       width: 250px;
       position:absolute; top:540px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       left: 270px;
   }

   #TextArea17 {
        height: 75px;
        width:  645px;
        text-align:start;
        text-anchor:end;
        position: absolute; top:580px;
        border:hidden;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
        left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea18 {
        height: 30px;
        width:  640px;
        text-align:start;
        text-anchor:end;
        position: absolute; top:660px;
        border:hidden;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
        scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
        left: 0px;
    }

   #TextArea19 {
       width: 240px;
       position: absolute; top: 700px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea20 {
       height: 15px;
       width: 400px;
       position: absolute; top: 760px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea21 {
       height: 15px;
       width: 400px;
       position: absolute; top: 800px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea22 {
       height: 15px;
       width: 400px;
       position: absolute; top: 820px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea23 {
       height: 15px;
       width: 400px;
       position: absolute; top: 840px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea24 {
       height: 10px;
       width: 400px;
       font-size:smaller;
       position: absolute; top: 880px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }

   #TextArea25 {
       height: 40px;
       width: 550px;
       font-size: x-small;
       position: absolute; top: 895px;
       scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
       scrollbar-base-color: #fff;
       border:hidden;
       left: 0px;
   }
```

And finally here is the code behind function: (Edited: 10-10-2013: 14:22:GTM+1)

```
protected void SaveAsPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl middlesector = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("middlesector");

        string strHtml = null;
        //MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
        Server.Execute("OfferteForm1.aspx", strWriter);
        strHtml = strWriter.ToString();
        strWriter.Close();
        strWriter.Dispose();
        iTextSharp.text.Image addLogo = default(iTextSharp.text.Image);
        addLogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("Images") + "/VisserSupplies.jpg");
        iTextSharp.text.Document docWorkingDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 40);
        StringReader srdDocToString = null;
        try
        {
            PdfWriter pdfWrite = default(PdfWriter);
            var fileCounter = 1;
            while (File.Exists("C:/Users/milans/Documents/PDFs/" + textarea11.InnerText + " - " + fileCounter + ".pdf"))
            {
                fileCounter++;
            }
            pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docWorkingDocument, new FileStream("C:/Users/milans/Documents/PDFs/" + textarea11.InnerText + " - " + fileCounter + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            srdDocToString = new StringReader(strHtml);
            docWorkingDocument.Open();
            addLogo.ScalePercent(50);
            addLogo.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
            docWorkingDocument.Add(addLogo);
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWrite, docWorkingDocument, srdDocToString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((docWorkingDocument != null))
            {
                docWorkingDocument.Close();
                docWorkingDocument.Dispose();
            }
            if ((srdDocToString != null))
            {
                srdDocToString.Close();
                srdDocToString.Dispose();
            }
        }
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", "window.open('C:/Users/milans/Documents/PDFs/" + textarea11.InnerText + ".pdf" + "','_blank','location=0,menubar=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0');", true);
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

I get an error at:
    Server.Execute("middlesector", strWriter);
And the same error for:
    Server.Execute("OfferteForm1.aspx", strWriter);

It has to do with permissions for IUSRS_machinename and ASPNET users.
But I don't know how to add permissions since I don't have a Manifest and somehow can't create one.

I've also tried:
    Server.HtmlDecode("middlesector", strWriter);
And:
    Server.HtmlDecode("OfferteForm1.aspx", strWriter);

It does compile a PDF but it only has the image.
All I want is for the XMLWorker to include the filled in form in the middlesector Div.

Comment: You're using `HTMLWorker` and that class doesn't look at the CSS. Try XML Worker instead: http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker

Comment: The problem is that I'm using the older version of iTextSharp because it has a difference license agreement.

Comment: As @BrunoLowagie said, `HTMLWorker` doesn't support CSS so there is no solution down that path unless you want to write your own parser. The official solution is to use `XMLWorker`. Also, there are many myths out there about the 4.x (2.1.7) version being "free", you might want to check into that more. http://www.lowagie.com/license

Comment: I'm now using 'XMLWorker' but I've got some trouble using it. I want to put only one div with it's contents in the PDF, but I can't find a single example where this is done. It worked with HTMLWorker using this.div.RenderControl('TextWriter') but obviously it omitted the CSS. Anyone know how to do this?